# Python framework best suited for building a 2-sided marketplace

Tags: python, python-3.x, frameworks

I am planning to develop a 2-sided marketplace which will have much of the functionality of Odesk.com. I'm aware that certain python frameworks lend themselves innately to certain types of projects (i.e. Django for blogs/CMS-type apps; Tornado for social networks; etc.) and was wondering if there is a framework, hopefully python3-ready, that is especially suitable for building out this sort of platform/marketplace. I will have user accounts on both sides, payment system, private communications/messaging, project management and workflow tools, etc.

Corollary: I am tempted to start with Flask, as I'm attracted to it's lightweight design. But will Flask be able to handle the complexities of a marketplace app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Although an extremely broad question, I will add my two cents by suggesting you look into Pyramid (more commonly referred to by its predecessor Pylons.)

It's a very flexible framework which will allow you to write your site without having to worry too much about framework "restrictions" and limitations. Whereas Django is the quintessential "batteries included" framework, Pyramid relies more heavily on using assorted, not inherently built-in components (hence the flexibility.)

From my experience with Django, it is very simple to use, if it provides exactly what you want. If you want to deviate from the standard, things will get more complex. As for Flask, I love its lightweight design, but as you said, it may be a bit too minimalistic for your preferences. Pyramid shines in it's flexibility; however, it requires a bit more of a learning curve than something like Django (that said, I actually find Pyramid far easier to work with – but that's my opinion)

From their website:

```
"As of this writing, Pyramid has been tested under Python 2.6.8, 
Python 2.7.3, Python 3.2.3, and Python 3.3b1. Pyramid does not run 
under any version of Python before 2.6."
```

The Pyramid website:
http://www.pylonsproject.org

Comment: Thanks very much, John. I've heard good things about Pyramid. Seems like a very good middle of the road option. I'll look more deeply into it.

Comment: You're very welcome - I'm glad I could help! On a different note, seeing as you're new to StackOverflow, we really appreciate users to accept answers (by clicking the green checkmark) when they sufficiently answer the asked question. And, as a rule of thumb, questions should be as objective as possible. Regardless, welcome to the community and happy coding!